# What is Frankenstein's monster made of in the original novel?

Tags: frankensteins-monster

This question started as a discussion in the commentaries of [What mammalian biological constraints would have to be relaxed/changed in order to allow Victorian style mixing of body parts?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/70755/what-mammalian-biological-constraints-would-have-to-be-relaxed-changed-in-order)

The popular idea is that the monster is made out of pieces of corpses, sewn together, but... two arguments against this:

(1) Quote from ch. 4:

> Although I possessed the capacity of bestowing animation, yet to prepare a frame for the reception of it, with all its intricacies of fibres, muscles, and veins, still remained a work of inconceivable difficulty and labour. I doubted at first whether I should attempt the creation of a being like myself, or one of simpler organization; but my imagination was too much exalted by my first success to permit me to doubt of my ability to give life to an animal as complex and wonderful as man.

Sewing parts is equally easy/difficult for humans and animals.

(2) The idea of multiple body pieces is incompatible with the subsequent plot:

> Frankenstein destroys the second (female) creature because he don't want a race of monsters. It's really difficult making a sterile creature from pieces of corpses?

Relevant link: [What is Frankenstein's monster made of?](http://fabledlands.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/what-is-frankensteins-monster-made-of.html) Also, [the novel](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/84/84-h/84-h.htm) in Gutenberg.org.

EDIT for clarification:

The quote (1) plus the previous research of "... the natural decay and corruption of the human body." suggests some type of guided "taratoembriological" process starting from raw materials simpler than body parts. Some type of non magical Hellraiser-style resurrection.

Relevant ch. 20 quote for (2):

> Even if they were to leave Europe and inhabit the deserts of the new world, yet one of the first results of those sympathies for which the daemon thirsted would be children, and a race of devils would be propagated upon the earth who might make the very existence of the species of man a condition precarious and full of terror. Had I right, for my own benefit, to inflict this curse upon everlasting generations?

If Frankenstein don't want this,

> making a female monster without an uterus is trivially easy sewing parts, while arguably impossible by "taratoembriological" process.

Comment: [It's people!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9IKVj4l5GU4).

Comment: Could you clarify how either of your two points constitutes an argument against? The first appears to say "building a human-like creature seemed like an insurmountable task, but in my pride I resolved to do it anyway", which doesn't offer much, and the second seems like a non sequitur.

Comment: @hobbs, edited for clarification.

Comment: What is taratoembriological supposed to mean?

Comment: You appear to be trying to ask two different questions here 1) **What is the Monster made out of?** and 2) **Why didn't Frankenstein sterilise the female monster?**

Comment: @Valorum, generating a monster by a process similar in some sense to the natural embryological development.

Comment: @Valorum, my (2) is relevant for your 1). Your 1) is my question. My (2) is an argument against the popular idea of body parts,

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla - I think you'd be better asking (2) as a brand new question.

Comment: *Frankenstein* isn’t exactly known as hard sci-fi, or otherwise for its internal consistency. So the fact that Dr Frankenstein forgot he could remove the uterus is completely in line with with the out-of-Universe explanation of lack of care on the writer’s part.

Comment: @Valorum, I've reverted your edit because I want use (2) as argument against the popular image of body parts and conserve the clarifications asked by hobbs.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, the supposed lack of care is too egregious. I can't accept it as out-of-Universe explanation.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla “lack of care” might have been the wrong phrase as there are two meanings to it. I meant that the author *didn’t* care about these minutae: it just wasn’t her priority. What people value in science fiction has changed tremendously over time, and as far as I know, expectations of internal consistency in fiction are relatively recent.

Comment: Your suggestion of a "taratoembriological" process as the reason why sterilization is impossible is interesting, though it seems like *quite* a leap. In fact, quote (1) seems like evidence *against* this idea, since it sounds like the "frame" is a *lifeless* body that is then *imbued* with "animation." (This also seems like it would more closely match the Victorian idea of how life worked.)

Comment: In general, I don't think the fact that Frankenstein couldn't (or didn't think to) sterilize the female monster is very strong evidence one way or the other for whether or not the monsters are made out of harvested parts.

Comment: As for an explanation for why Frankenstein doesn't create a sterile female monster, I suspect it's merely that Frankenstein's (and probably the monster's) *definition of a female* would *require* fertility, especially since the monsters are conceived as the prototypical first members of a new species. I.e., I think he believes that to create a sterile female for the monster would be to break his promise to the monster, in nearly the same way that destroying his second creation entirely is.

Comment: @KyleStrand, you are right about the ideas of the time. The Hellraiser-style un-putrefaction is a better image.

Comment: "I've reverted your edit because I want use (2) as argument " I don't think the question should have any part in arguing an answer. Please ask clear, well defined questions with direct answers.

Comment: I could only understand *Frankenstein*'s scientific parts by considering the natural world in that book to be magical, not realistic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By all accounts it seems the others here have very well addressed the first half of this question and settled how Frankenstein’s creation/monster/“son” was constructed. (For convenience, I will be using the popular nickname “Adam” here to refer to the created being). However, it seems either I or they have misread Dr. Victor’s fears and his later exchange with Adam.

It is true that the text shows that Victor clearly feared that his actions would enable more inhuman and nearly invincible beings to come into the world. However, he never specifically said they would do so through biological reproduction.
This text is from directly before Victor destroyed the second creation:

> “I trembled and my heart failed within me, when, on looking up, I saw by the light of the moon the daemon at the casement. A ghastly grin wrinkled his lips as he gazed on me, where I sat fulfilling the task which he had allotted to me. Yes, he had followed me in my travels; he had loitered in forests, hid himself in caves, or taken refuge in wide and desert heaths; and he now came to mark my progress and claim the fulfilment of my promise.”
>   *quoted from the Guttenberg e-text of the book located here: https://www.gutenberg.org/files/84/84-h/84-h.htm

I have always read this not simply as a statement that Adam was tracking Victor, but that he was studying the process by which his kind is made. Remember how easily he learned to speak? This would mean that the act of creating one sterile companion for Adam could have enabled him to make more.

And even if she was infertile, Victor wasn’t comfortable with there being one Adam, much less two. Even if Victor could have guaranteed their number would never go above two, there was no guarantee she alone wouldn’t be a like a demon and a monster to mankind.

Comment: Very good in-universe explanation. +1.

Comment: Thank you. And perhaps I’m overestimating him, but I’ve always been impressed by Adam.

Comment: Also, while some interpretations try to explain away the speed of his learning (such as the 1994 film) there are always counterarguments. Ie: while I love the quote “not things learned so much as remembered,” even in that film the brain was from a legendary surgeon, so some room for supposition still exists…

Answer (score 23):

The 'monster' is made out of various body parts, either those collected fresh from the graveyard or those that were stored for future use. The good doctor makes repeated references to his *"materials"*, this being his own coy expression for the body pieces he's harvesting from corpses.

> *Nor could I consider the magnitude and complexity of my plan as any
> argument of its impracticability. It was with these feelings that I
> began the creation of a human being. **As the minuteness of the parts
> formed a great hindrance to my speed, I resolved, contrary to my first
> intention, to make the being of a gigantic stature, that is to say,
> about eight feet in height, and proportionably large.** After having
> formed this determination and **having spent some months in successfully
> collecting and arranging my materials,** I began.*
>
> <sub><sup>Frankenstein: Chapter 5</sup></sub>

and

> *How can I describe my emotions at this catastrophe, or how delineate the wretch whom with such infinite pains and care I had endeavoured to form? **His limbs were in proportion, and I had selected his features as beautiful.***
>
> <sub><sup>Frankenstein: Chapter 5</sup></sub>

and latterly,

> ***I now also began to collect the materials necessary for my new
> creation,** and this was to me like the torture of single drops of water
> continually falling on the head. Every thought that was devoted to it
> was an extreme anguish, and every word that I spoke in allusion to it
> caused my lips to quiver, and my heart to palpitate.*
>
> <sub><sup>Frankenstein: Chapter 19</sup></sub>

---

As to whether such a thing is possible, you've neglected to add the second part of your quote, in which the good Doctor informs us of his *growing prowess* as a surgeon...

> *...but my imagination was too much exalted by my first success to permit me to doubt of my ability to give life to an animal as complex and wonderful as man.*
>
> *The materials at present within my command hardly appeared adequate to
> so arduous an undertaking, but **I doubted not that I should ultimately
> succeed.** I prepared myself for a multitude of reverses; my operations
> might be incessantly baffled, and at last my work be imperfect, **yet
> when I considered the improvement which every day takes place in
> science and mechanics, I was encouraged to hope my present attempts
> would at least lay the foundations of future success.** Nor could I
> consider the magnitude and complexity of my plan as any argument of
> its impracticability. It was with these feelings that I began the
> creation of a human being. As the minuteness of the parts formed a
> great hindrance to my speed, I resolved, contrary to my first
> intention, to make the being of a gigantic stature, that is to say,
> about eight feet in height, and proportionably large. **After having
> formed this determination and having spent some months in successfully
> collecting and arranging my materials, I began.***
>
> <sub><sup>Frankenstein: Chapter 4</sup></sub>

Comment: The part about how the minuteness of the parts slowed him down leads me to believe that he actually built a cadaver from the skeleton up, sewing individual muscles, veins & such together as he went. This doesn't change your answer, but it's still a far cry from the popular idea of him slapping some arms & legs onto a torso and frying it with lightning.

Comment: He just could not start with a downsized prototype, could he. Would have made things so much easier (and the story less dramatic).

Comment: @Omegacron "Popular idea of him slapping some arms & legs onto a torso and frying it with lightning" - correct, people are confusing him with Darth Vader.

Comment: See my comment to the another answer. Never is said that the materials are complete body parts. Also, see my edit.

Comment: @Omegacron, your idea is compatible with (1) but not with (2).

Comment: Your first quote is actually what led me to believe upon reading the novel that the "materials" are *not* parts of bodies. Since he *explicitly mentions* the "intricacies of fibres, muscles, and veins" as a hindrance, it's clear that *scaling up* the monster means scaling up the size of the "fibres, muscles, and veins". How is this possible if he's just *collecting* them? Beyond that, your answer seems to rest entirely on the assumption that "materials" means "animal and/or human tissue." I have no idea what evidence there is to support this assumption.

Comment: @KyleStrand when I read it, I assumed he was just collecting large parts from large former individuals, and that in Shelley's imaginary natural world, these parts were "scaled up" appropriately for Frankenstein's needs. Maybe that's not what was meant; it certainly doesn't make much sense. As for what evidence there is to think that "materials" means "corpse parts", did you miss Mithrandir's answer?

Comment: I read Mithrandir's answer after yours, and indeed the quote is much better evidence for that idea. I don't think your answer should depend on a different answer, though, so I left my comment in place.

Comment: @KyleStrand - I strongly considered incorporating that quote into my answer but decided against it since it would detract from Mithrandir's answer.

Comment: I think you should really include it, possibly with a credit to Mithrandir for finding it.

Answer (score 18):

**It does in fact appear to be human bits.**

> It was indeed but a passing trance, that only made me feel with renewed acuteness so soon as, the unnatural stimulus ceasing to operate, I returned to my old habits. **I collected bones from charnel-houses and disturbed, with profane fingers, the secrets of the human frame.** In a solitary chamber, or rather cell, at the top of the house, and separate from all the other apartments by a gallery and staircase, I kept my workshop of filthy creation......The **dissecting room and the slaughterhouse furnished many of my materials**;
>   <sub>-*Frankenstein*, Chapter 4</sub>

Comment: Counterargument: Frankenstein says that "I must also observe the natural decay and corruption of the human body." Frankenstein collects corpses for research.

Comment: A slaughterhouse would not contain human materials, but rather those of nonhuman animals (a dissecting room could be either one). I think the statements are compatible with the idea that he constructed new organs out of basic materials like animal tissue (and possibly inorganic material as well) rather than simply sewing together complete organs from people or nonhuman animals.